# Как сгенерировать случайное число в заданном диапазоне?

Tags: delphi, случайные-числа

Можно ли задать случайное число (random) в каком-то диапазоне, например от 100 до 200.
А не с нуля...

```
random(201) // 0 - 200
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
random(100)+100
```

Comment: Только уточню, будут числа от 100 до 199. От 100 до 200 нужен код `random(101)+100`.

Answer (score 1):

В модуле `Math` есть специальная функция:

```
function RandomRange(const RangeFrom, RangeTo: Integer): Integer;
```

> Delphi функция `RandomRange` генерирует произвольное целое число ( integer ) в пределах диапазона `RangeFrom` и `RangeTo`.
>
> Она обеспечивает более удобную версию функции `Random` модуля `System`.
>
> Оба используют псевдослучайную последовательность чисел 2^32 значений. Каждый раз, когда Вы выполняете вашу программу, сгенерированные значения будут одни и те же, если Вы не установите генератор в произвольную часть последовательности, используя функции `Randomize` или `RandSeed`.

http://delphibasics.ru/RandomRange.php